# What is the exposure time of the navigation camera on Ingenuity?

Tags: nasa, perseverance, ingenuity

Today's first image from Ingenuity's navigation camera shows a remarkable lack of motion blur in the shadow of the rotors, despite them turning at 2600 RPM:

[image]

The [factsheet](https://rotorcraft.arc.nasa.gov/Publications/files/Balaram_AIAA2018_0023.pdf) tells us:

> Navigation (NAV) Camera. This is a global-shutter, nadir pointed grayscale 640 by 480 pixel sensor (Omnivision OV7251) mounted to a Sunny optics module. It has a field-of-view (FOV) of 133 deg (horizontal) by 100 deg(vertical) with an average Instantaneous Field-of-view (IFOV) of 3.6 mRad/pixel, and is capable of acquiring images at 10 frames/sec. Visual features are extracted from the images and tracked from frame to frame to provide a velocity estimate.

It makes sense that for tracking visual features you'd want a short exposure to reduce motion blur. What was the exposure time?

Comment: related with substantial overlap [How did Ingenuity get such a sharp image of the shadow of its own high-speed helicopter blades?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51492/12102)

Answer (score 1):

[4 microseconds](https://twitter.com/psilynt/status/1384215014630846473), as it seems like it was a [Blackfly S camera](https://www.flir.com/products/blackfly-s-usb3/). At least, that is the min exposure time possible with that camera. The sensor is [Omnivision OV7251](https://rotorcraft.arc.nasa.gov/Publications/files/Balaram_AIAA2018_0023.pdf), according to the document of parts.

Comment: That FLIR camera uses a very different sensor, how does it compare to the camera on Ingenuity?

Comment: Many years ago, I built and programmed an image processing to watch probes in a centrifuge at 3000 RPM. About 4 microseconds to get sharp images. 4 µs of 20 ms for one revolution, that is 4.3 arcseconds to 360 degrees. The rotor moves 4.3 arcseconds or 0.072 degrees in 4 µs,